# How to extend and override a style object reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a base style object similar to the below one:

```
const baseGridStyle = {
  gridStyle: {
    '& .ag-header-row, .ag-filter-input:input': {
      fontSize: '14px',
      backgroundColor: COLORS.dark_blue,
      minWidth: '100%',
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I am trying to extend and override the above style object like below:

```
  const extendedGridStyle = (theme) => ({
  gridStyle: {
    '& .ag-header-row': {
      fontSize: '16px'
    }
  }
})
```

I tried to extend the base style using spread syntax like below but it overrides the gridStyle property of baseGridStyle object with the extendedGridStyle

```
const extendedGridStyle = (theme) => ({
  ...baseGridStyle,
  gridStyle: {
    '& .ag-header-row': {
      fontSize: '16px'
    }
  }
})
```

I tried using lodash's merge function to merge both the objects. Since the extendedGridStyle is a function, the merge function doesn't merge the styles. is there a way to do this (probably jss-like way)?

I am unable to proceed further due to this issue. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Update 1:
I tried the answer suggested below by Stuart. What happens is, if I have a

```
'& .ag-header-row' //class A
{
 fontSize: '14px,
 border-width: '1px'
}
```

in **baseGridStyle** and I have a

```
'& .ag-header-row' //class A
{
fontSize: '16px
}
```

inside extendedGridStyle, the class A in base grid is being overridden with the class A of extendedGridStyle. Is there a way to retain the border-width while only overidding fontSize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if your intention is to merge them tougether without loosing the original key then what you are looking for is:

```
const extendedGridStyle = (theme) => ({
  gridStyle: {
     ...baseGridStyle.gridStyle,
    '& .ag-header-row': {
      fontSize: '16px'
    }
  }
})
```

And that will end being something like this :

```
const extendedGridStyle = (theme) => ({

  gridStyle: {
     '& .ag-header-row, .ag-filter-input:input': {
      fontSize: '14px',
      backgroundColor: COLORS.dark_blue,
      minWidth: '100%',
    },
    '& .ag-header-row': {
      fontSize: '16px'
    }
  }
})
```

Which i think is what you are looking for.

EDIT: 
So what I understand is classes from A and B are the same and you want to merge them together. without loosing the cssProps. if thats the case then you can merge deep them using  a function like

```
const merge = (target, source) => {
  // Iterate through `source` properties and if an `Object` set property to merge of `target` and `source` properties
  for (const key of Object.keys(source)) {
    if (source[key] instanceof Object) Object.assign(source[key], merge(target[key], source[key]))
  }

  // Join `target` and modified `source`
  Object.assign(target || {}, source)
  return target
}
```

you would do the following :

```
const extendedGridStyle = (theme) => (merge(baseGridStyle,{

  gridStyle: {
    '& .ag-header-row': {
      fontSize: '16px'
    }
  })
})
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I tried the above solution. What happens is, if I have a class A {prop1: value1, prop2: value2} in baseGridStyle and I have a class A {prop1: value3} inside extendedGridStyle, the class A in base grid is being overridden with the class A of extendedGridStyle. Is there a way to retain the prop2 while only overidding prop1

Comment: when you say class A you mean class as in css class or you mean a js object?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused. I mean css class. Consider '& .ag-header-row' instead of class A